# How to use blobKey to pull out the names,content/type and size of the file from blob store in Google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

As i gone through some of the examples i didn't find a right way to accomplish this logic

so, Here i m trying to upload a file in blob store,by using the key of that file i m unable to retrieve the name of the file,content type like so...

here is the index page :

index.jsp page

```
   <%
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
   %>
 <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" 
       method="post"          
       enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="myFile" id="upload" multiple/><br>
   <input type="submit" value="submit form">
   </form>
```

upload .java

```
   DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService()    ;
   Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
   BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");

   res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());
```

BlobstoreServlet.java

```
    BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
    blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```

so while running it automatically creating an entity name *blobinfo* where i can find all the details but unable to retrieve from there.
In upload.java, able to find blobKey.toString which is the key exactly.so here is the point with the help of the key i cannot fetch the filed of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
private BlobInfoFactory infoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();

BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
BlobInfo info = infoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
```

Comment: one more question Andrei after uploading the file it automatically changes the url,and is there any way to include a new column in the blobstore.

Comment: as u can see in index.jsp page i used `<form action="<%=blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post">` this line to call the servlet,after servlet callin upload.java file i used redirect to open the image,but if m not using the redirect it automatically changes the UrL,if its there anything left u can ask.

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: just wanted to stay on that page itself.

Comment: Then do not redirect. Add an image to your current page.

Comment: but i dont do redirect it automatically does..as i tried that alot

Comment: Remove this line: res.sendRedirect("/serve?blob-key=" + blobKey.getKeyString());